# add or remove item from DataGrid - vb.net compact framework

Tags: vb.net, datagrid, windows-mobile, compact-framework, handheld

I am working on a project that allow users to get order in restaurant with handheld which is windows mobile device. I used datagrid to show existing order and wanted to add item by clicking on a button, or remove item by selecting from datagrid to change the order. Thus, could you please guys help me to figure out what is the best way to working on existing database items. Thanks in advance.

so far my code is,

Getting existing order from database

```
Public Shared Function MenuItems(ByVal groupNo As Integer) As List(Of Menus)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("", Ayar.baglanti)
    Dim menuItem As New List(Of Menus)

    Try
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ToppingAutoID, BasePrice, ToppingName, PrinterName, Special, Normal, Irregular," & _
            " NavigationID, ModifiersCharge, taxRate, JustNavigate, Terminator, ItemQuantity, ExtraCharge, TripleCharge, " & _
            " HalfCharge, OneThirdCharge, OneForthCharge, NoDiscountItem FROM MenuToppings WHERE GroupID = @groupID"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@groupID", groupNo)
        Dim data As New DataSet
        data.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, "menuitem")
        Dim dt As DataTable = data.Tables("menuitem")
        ''
        For Each r As DataRow In dt.Rows
            Dim item As New Menus
            item.Toppingautoid = r("ToppingAutoID")
            item.Baseprice = r("BasePrice")
            item.Toppingname = r("ToppingName")
            item.Itemquantity = r("ItemQuantity")
            menuItem.Add(item)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        log.log("MenuItem()fonksiyonunda hata oluştu.", ex.Message)
    End Try
    MenuItems = menuItem
End Function
```

Listing existing order on datagrid

```
  Public Function siparisGoster()        
    Dim isModifed As Boolean = False

    Dim skl As New DataGridTableStyle
    Dim kolon1, kolon2, kolon3 As New DataGridTextBoxColumn
    kolon1.MappingName = "Itemno"
    kolon1.HeaderText = "MADAKAFA"
    kolon1.Width = -1

    kolon2.MappingName = "Itemdesc"
    kolon2.Width = 300

    kolon3.MappingName = "Itemamount"
    kolon3.Width = 10

    skl.GridColumnStyles.Add(kolon1)
    skl.GridColumnStyles.Add(kolon2)
    skl.GridColumnStyles.Add(kolon3)

    If isModifed = False Then
        Dim ord As Order = Order.GetTableOrder(tableNo)

        Dim bs As New BindingSource
        bs.DataSource = ord.GetOrderItems
        skl.MappingName = bs.GetListName(Nothing)
        DataGridItems.BackColor = Color.White
        DataGridItems.ColumnHeadersVisible = False
        DataGridItems.RowHeadersVisible = False

        DataGridItems.TableStyles.Clear()
        DataGridItems.TableStyles.Add(skl)
        DataGridItems.DataSource = bs

    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Paul Yao describes both, a manual and automatic, in-place editing in his book Programming the Compact Framework (VB.NET and C# editions available). You may register at http://www.paulyao.com/cfbook/code to get the code of chapter 8.

excerpt:

```
    Private Sub cmdEdit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                             ByVal e As System.EventArgs _
                             ) _
                             Handles cmdEdit.Click
      With dgrdProjects.CurrentCell
         '  Check the DataSource's column's name
         '     If it is "ctTasks", do not update.
         If dgrdProjects.TableStyles("Projects"). _
                           GridColumnStyles(.ColumnNumber). _
                              MappingName = "ctTasks" Then
            MessageBox.Show( _
               "Count of tasks only changes as the " & _
               "result of adding / removing a task.")
            Exit Sub
         End If
         '  Position textEdit for in-place editing.
         textEdit.Bounds = dgrdProjects.GetCellBounds _
                                 (.RowNumber, .ColumnNumber)
         '  Load the CurrentCell's value into textEdit.
         textEdit.Text = dgrdProjects.Item _
                                 (.RowNumber, .ColumnNumber)
         '  Highlight the text.
         textEdit.SelectAll()
         '  Show textEdit and set the focus to it.
         textEdit.Visible = True
         textEdit.Focus()
      End With
      '  Set Form GUI state to "Editing".
      Me.SetEditingState(True)
   End Sub
   ...
   Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                               ByVal e As System.EventArgs _
                               ) _
                               Handles cmdUpdate.Click
      '  Move the contents of textEdit
      '     into the CurrentCell
      With dgrdProjects
         .Item(.CurrentCell.RowNumber, _
               .CurrentCell.ColumnNumber) = textEdit.Text
      End With
      '  Set Form GUI state to "Not Editing".
      Me.SetEditingState(False)
    End Sub
```

The book is well worth to buy it. It is one of my favorite CF starter.